# grails show flash message in view while executing

Tags: flash, grails, view, controller, message

In my view I have a section for my flash messages:

```
<g:if test="${flash.message}">
    <section id="flashTile">
        <div class="alert fade in">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a>
        <p>${flash.message}</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</g:if>
```

At some point in the view I call an action in my controller:

```
<g:form action="doAction">
   <g:submitButton class="ghbtn" name="doAction" />                 
</g:form>
```

The controller action is similar to:

```
def doAction() {
    try {
        flash.message = 'Computing...'
        webserviceService.compute()
        flash.message = 'Computed'
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        flash.message = 'Could not compute'
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }
}
```

When I click on the `doAction` button and `webserviceService.compute()` is executed successfully, I get the 'Computed' message; when an error occurs I get the 'could not compute' message. This works fine.

Since `webserviceService.compute()` takes a few seconds to execute, I want to inform the user the system received the request and is processing it, otherwise the user might it's not working and click the button again.

I added another flash message 'Computing...', which should show up immediately after clicking on `doAction` until, the webservice is executed.

The workflow should look something like this:

click `doAction` -> show 'Computing...'

`webserviceService.compute()` executed -> 'Computing...' is replaced by 'Computed' or 'Could not compute'

The only problem here is 'Computing...' never shows up. Any hints on this?

---

thanks for the hint. I've now changed my form to

```
<g:form action="calculate" onsubmit="return calculating()">
```

and

```
<script type="text/Javascript">                      
    function calculating() {   
        alert("come here");
        return true;
</script>
```

instead of the alert line I want to change flash.message, but sofar I haven't found anything useful on this. 
Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Have you considered disabling your button after it is clicked the first time to prevent double-clicks?

Comment: This would be a nice workaround, but still I want to solve it the way I've described above

Comment: It seems that an Ajax request would do the trick for you, but then there is no flash message availble...

Answer (score 3):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how the request/response cycle works.  Based on this:

```
flash.message = 'Computing...'
webserviceService.compute()
flash.message = 'Computed'
redirect(action: "list")
return
```

What makes you think 'Computing' will ever get returned to the view?  It won't.  You're going to have to apply some JavaScript to your problem.

You can disable the button as JoshDM stated or use JavaScript to display a message telling the user to wait.  Both of which would need to happen on the click event of the submit button.

There's an Ajax solution here as well but given your current understanding I'm afraid that would just complicate matters for you at this time.

Comment: I would also suggest to use Ajax and I agree that it would complicate matters for the thread owner, but on the other hand: what time would be better to learn about Ajax than now? :)